# How to automatically bulk/batch append the filenames of my html files to the titles of those files within the <title> tags?

Tags: html, filenames, title

I would like to automatically bulk/batch append the filenames of my html files to the titles of those files within the  tags inside the source code of those files. Is this possible?

I have converted a book in PDF format into html - using Acrobat Pro DC. I have the book divided into hundreds of html files now, each named like "part1.htm" or "part68.htm" etc. I am using the name/title of the book as the title for each of those html files within the  tags inside the source code of those files. But, I would like those titles within the  tags to reflect the corresponding "part number", i.e. the filenames of the files within which they are residing, by appending the filename at the end of the corresponding 'title'.

For example:
1. The name/title of the book is, say, "Archaeological Heritage of India".
2. One of the html filename is "part68.htm".
3. The title within the  tags in the source code of the file "part68.htm" is :  Archaeological Heritage of India.

Now, I would like to turn the title *"Archaeological Heritage of India"* in that file's html source-code into: *"Archaeological Heritage of India**_part68**"* (**NOTE:** minus the ".htm"!!). If it were only 1 or a few files, I could have done it manually easily. But, doing this manually in hundreds of files would be an excruciatingly laborious, painful and time-consuming task.

My question is: is it possible to automate this task? Is there any way to copy all the html filenames (not the extensions) and append them to the corresponding source-code titles within the "title" tags in a batch/bulk manner? If possible, then how??

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you program in any language?

Comment: @LittleS : Not really. I can sometimes tweak / make minor modifications to other people's javascript code to some extent to make it suit my purposes - but that's all.